# Permutations with Condition

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, permutations

I have looked at this old problem in my textbook:

> How many permutations $\pi \in S_n (n \geq 3)$ meet the requirement: $\pi (1) < \pi (2) $ or $\pi (1) < \pi (3)$?

I am not sure how to proceed, $\pi (1)$ means at position 1, or?

I know that the answer is $\frac23 n!$, but I seek the explanation behind it.

Comment: Yes, $\pi(1)$ means position. Maybe one can try it for small $n$ and than try an induction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disregard $\pi(k)$ for $k>3$. We can think of the values $\pi(1), \pi(2), \pi(3)$ as Low, Medium, and High, in one of six orderings:

> **L M H**
>   **L H M**
>   **M L H**
>   **M H L**
>   H L M
>   H M L

The first four satisfy the given property, corresponding to $\frac46 = \frac23$ of all permutations of $[n]$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

For $1,2,3$ there are the following $6$ orders:

- $123$
- $132$
- $213$
- $231$
- $312$
- $321$

In $4$ of the $6$ cases ($\frac23$ of the total) the $1$ appears before the $2$ or the $3$.

Does that ring a bell?